# USACO Code Submission Problem - Output File Missing

Tags: python

I've started practicing for the USACO contest tomorrow, I'm relativly new so I'm not too familiar with their input/output methods. Here's the code I submitted to the website

```
n = int(input())
a = input()
b = input()

swap_number = 0
a_list = []
b_list = []

for i in range(n):
  if a[i] != b[i]:
    a_list.append(a[i])
    b_list.append(b[i])

one_value = 0
two_value = 0

for x in range(len(a_list)):
  if a_list[x] == "H":
    one_value += 1
  else:
    two_value += 1


list = [one_value,two_value]
list.sort()

swap_number = list[0] + (list[1]-list[0])

print(swap_number)
```

after loading for a couple minutes, it displayed:
Your output file breedflip.out:
[File missing!]

I rewrote, retested every problem using this simple code, but still receive the same error
Would this code not create an output file and how can I put the outputted answer in the file

Comment: check whether the question asked to print//return the output

Comment: it wants me to print the answer

Comment: Can you share the link of this problem directly?  Without the context, it's hard to *guess* what's expected.

Comment: heres the link to the problem
http://www.usaco.org/index.php?page=viewproblem2&cpid=1012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add these two lines in your beginning of codes: (just test and it passed with *my revised code*)  Your code might not be working!

```py
import sys

sys.stdin = open('breedflip.in', 'r')
sys.stdout = open('breedflip.out', 'w')

n = int(input())
a = list(input())   # list
b = list(input())
...........
```